# Tell mathematica to move on to the next step

Tags: programming, conditional

```
If[4 == 2 + 2, GoAhead, Abort[]]; 33 + 55
88

If[4 == 2 + 2, 915, Abort[]]; 33 + 55
88

If[4 == 2 + 22, GoAhead, Abort[]]; 33 + 55
Abort[]

If[4 == 2 + 22, 915, Abort[]]; 33 + 55
Abort[]
```

There is no difference.

What method is prefered to tell mathematica to move on to the next step?

Is it just a matter of personal preference?

Personally I often use this technique in early stage of a code, to filter out bad, inappropriate input.

+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-after receiving some comments+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-

There is no command like `GoAhead`, and there is nothing important in `915`.
But to make `If` sentence well-formed(antonym of ill-formed), there should be something in ( ? ). If[4==2+2, ( ? ), y=2]

**Anyway I'll rephrase my question :**

```
If[4==2+2, ?Do nothing?, y=2]
```

This means that if `4=2+2` is correct, do nothing, if wrong, set `y=2`. Can you express `do nothing`?

Comment: There is no defined command `GoAhead`, per my understanding. Did you forget a definition? It is not at all clear what you want or expect to happen here. What do the numbers mean? Can you clarify what you mean by `”move on to the next step”`? The next step of what? This is quite a confusing question as it is now.

Comment: if I understand what you're trying to get at here (but I might not), you might be looking for something like `Confirm` with `Enclose` (and `Confirm`'s variants; see the docs). These essentially let you interrupt a computation and return a failure (and also let you include information in the generated `Failure` object).

Comment: Or, since you mentioned filtering out input, you might be looking for the following, which is more common: if you're filtering out inappropriate input to a *function* you're defining, use `/;` in the definition. For example, `f[x_, y_] := x - y /; x > y` will only apply the definition when `x > y` is `True`. Since everything after `/;` gets evaluated first, you can also include error messages if you want, while still preventing the definition from being applied gracefully. (`/;` can equivalently be placed before `:=` as a matter of style: `f[x_, y_] /; x > y := x - y`)

Comment: _Can you express do nothing_ may be `If[4 == 2 + 2, Null, y = 2]` or why not just `If[Not[4 == 2 + 5], y = 2]` ?  `If` in Mathematica is actually a function. a real function. This is not like other languages. `If[]`  takes its arguments and returns a return value. So the return value can be `Null`  somewhere deep in Mathematica source code, there is `If[....]:=Module[{},.....]` code

Comment: btw, `If[4 == 2 + 2, Null, y = 2]` should be the same as `If[4 == 2 + 2, , y = 2]` but I think it is more clear to put `Null` in there to be explicit.

Comment: Thank you all commenters, what I wanted is `Null`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, If your use case is to filter bad input, I recommend that you do that in the definition of your function (using e.g. multiple alternative definitions, with restrictive patterns on the arguments to accept only valid values, and then an unrestricted default definition to handle error messages; see [`Condition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html) and [`PatternTest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html)).

To answer your explicit question, though, I think you could just use the logical complement of your condition in an If function, I.e.  just look for the condition where you have to do something, rather than checking for those where you do nothing. In other words, instead of:

```
If[4 == 2 + 2, ?Do nothing?, y = 2]
```

Use:

```
If[Not[4 == 2 + 2], y = 2]
```

and all the other cases will automatically do nothing.